# How can I define a calculation in SSAS for counting greater than zero values?

Tags: sql-server, ssas, cube

I have a measure named `[Measures].[Qty Back Sale]` in a cube in SQL Server Analysis Services. It is the Sum of column `Qty_BackSale`. Now I want to define a measure that calculates the number of rows that `Qty_BackSale` is greater than zero.

How can I calculate it?

Comment: Are you maybe looking for the FILTER() function?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to add a named calculation to the fact table in the data source view. You would use an expression like `case when Qty_BackSale > 0 then 1 else 0 end`. Then just define a new measure based on this with the standard AggregateFunction `Sum`.

Answer (score 0):

No need to store the zero, else it encourages dense data.